# Duplicate related posts on Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm creating a website on Gatsby. I have a function that creates a related posts block on a post page. It works fine, but for some reason after a few seconds (about half a minute), some or all related posts are duplicated on the post page.

Is my `related.js` component.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";

const RelatedArticles = ({ posts }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {posts.map(({ node }) => {
        const title = node.frontmatter.title;
        return (
          <div key={node.fields.slug}>
            <div>
              <Link to={`/blog${node.fields.slug}`}>
                {title}
              </Link>
            </div>
            <small>{node.frontmatter.date}</small>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export const relatedArticlesQuery = graphql`
  query {
    allMdx(sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }) {
      edges {
        node {
          excerpt
          fields {
            slug
          }
          frontmatter {
            date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
            title
            tags
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

const RelatedPosts = (props) => {
  const related = [];

  return (
    <StaticQuery
      query={relatedArticlesQuery}
      render={(data) => {
        const {
            allMdx: { edges },
        } = data;

        // iterate through article vertex
        for (const vertex of edges) {
          // handle base case
          if (related.length >= props.limit) {
            continue;
          }

          // abstract tags
          const {
            frontmatter: { tags },
          } = vertex.node;

          // handle case where there are no tags or prop tags
          if (!tags || !props.tags) {
            continue;
          }

          const formattedTags = tags

          // ensure tags match and article is not the same as current
          if (
            props.tags.some((item) => formattedTags.includes(item)) &&
            props.title !== vertex.node.frontmatter.title
          ) {
            related.push(vertex);
          }
        }

        // render posts
        return (
          <div className="related">
            <h3>
              Вам может понравиться
            </h3>
            <RelatedArticles posts={related} />
          </div>
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default RelatedPosts
```

Is my blog post template

```
const BlogPost = ({ data , children }) => {
    const image = getImage(data.mdx.frontmatter.featuredImage)
    const tags = data.mdx.frontmatter.tags
    const categories = data.mdx.frontmatter.categories
    return (
        <Layout pageTitle={data.mdx.frontmatter.title}>
            <ul>{tags && tags
                .map(tag => tag.trim())
                .filter(tag => tag.length > 0)
                .map(tag => <li key={tag}><Link to={`/blog/tag/${_.kebabCase(transliterate(tag))}`}>{tag}</Link></li>)}
            </ul>
            <ul>{categories && categories
            .map(category => category.trim())
                .filter(category => category.length > 0)
                .map(category => <li key={category}><Link to={`/blog/category/${_.kebabCase(transliterate(category))}`}>{category}</Link></li>)}
            </ul>
            <p>{data.mdx.frontmatter.date}</p>
            <GatsbyImage
                image={image}
            />
            {children}
            <RelatedPosts tags={data.mdx.frontmatter.tags} limit={6} title={data.mdx.frontmatter.title} />
        </Layout>
    )
}

export const query = graphql`
    query ($id: String) {
        mdx(id: {eq: $id}) {
            frontmatter {
                title
                date(formatString: "DD MMMM YYYY")
                featuredImage {
                    childImageSharp {
                        gatsbyImageData
                    }
                }
                tags
                categories
                type

            }
            excerpt
            body
        }

    }
`

export const Head = ({ data }) => (
    <Seo
        title={data.mdx.frontmatter.title}
        description={data.mdx.excerpt}
    />
)

export default BlogPost
```

I can't figure out what the reason is. Some posts in the list are simply duplicated after about 20-30 seconds after the page loads. Could there be an error in the code somewhere?

[image]

Most likely, there are additional posts whose tags match not one, but several tags of the post being viewed. That is, if you watch Post-1 with tags tag-1, tag-2 and tag-3, you will have two posts as related posts Post-2 and Post-3 that have tag-1. But if, for example, Post-2 also has tag-2, then after some time it will be duplicated on the Post-1 page. It is necessary to make sure that posts are not duplicated if they have more than 1 matching tag with the current post

Answer (score -1):

I added `tags: []` in frontmatter to my posts in the `work type` so that there were no errors and now everything works fine